# Combine awk output field to corresponding integer

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to extract version numbers from lines in a file like below:

`grep abc | awk '{print $3}' somefile` and getting multiline output as:

```
7.2.5.200
7.3.4.100
```

I would like this output to be combined to an integer to use later as shown below:

expected output:

```
725200
734100
```

I tried using `split` function but looks like there is no join function in `awk`.
Any workaround for this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that really useful? I mean `7.2.1.23` and `7.2.12.3` would both map to `72123` so then you've lost presumably critical information.

Comment: Good catch. Let me check for some alternatives for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to sort to get the latest version you can use sort's `-V, --version-sort` arg.

Comment: If you're doing this to try to sort or compare or otherwise organise anything by version number, there are better ways to do it than first concatenating all the numbers into an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way, using `awk`:

```bash
grep abc | awk '{ gsub(/\./, "", $3); print $3}' somefile
725200
734100
```

but you hardly ever need to use `grep` when working with `awk`:

```bash
awk '/abc/ { gsub(/\./, "", $3); print $3}' somefile
725200
734100
```